# Free RF Simulation Software

Tags: rf, simulation

What free tools are there to simulate RF circuits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For normal [lumped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model) circuits, your favorite version of spice will work fine.

For analyzing matching networks, I've used [gsmc](http://www.qsl.net/ik5nax/).

For analyzing a layout and extracting parasitics and computing fields, I dunno.  It's usually easier to just build the circuit and see what happens.

Comment: I wonder @markrages why only Google thinks that software is malware?

Comment: http://sss-mag.com/pdf/rfosc.pdf   ltspice and GHz notes

Comment: other useful RF notes http://www.sss-mag.com/pdf.html

Comment: design tools http://www.sss-mag.com/tools.html

Comment: software index http://www.sss-mag.com/swindex.html

Comment: free RF tools http://www.sss-mag.com/swindexa.html#cad

Comment: Design topics http://www.sss-mag.com/destopics.html

Comment: better software with demos but best is $ https://www.comsol.com/rf-module  it is best due to physics mesh design analysis because RF must analyze conductor & dielectric geometry

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to check out QucsStudio. I've just started with it, and it seems too good to be true. These guys put more work into their documentation than most freeware has in the code. Very nice!!

http://dd6um.darc.de/QucsStudio/qucsstudio.html

Also, this site has a free Smith Chart, RF Filter, and Opamp filter design programs that may be useful to you.

http://www.iowahills.com

Comment: qucs is great and for this. it is designed and written by some ppl doing research into microwave and found nothing of use out there.

Answer (score 4):

HP AppCAD, available from: http://www.avagotech.com, may be helpful

Answer (score 2):

There's some possibility that [5Spice](http://www.5spice.com/index.htm) will do what you're looking for, although I can't guarantee it; you'll just have to give it a try and see.

Answer (score 1):

So far Qucs Studio os very good.  Translating the documentation (almost directly out of several microwave engineering books) into simulations can be challenging. SO.... do three of the tutorials FIRST to cut your teeth. I started with the L band amplifier tutorial - good stuff, but  advanced, get out your text books.  I'm two days in and I got a Bluetooth wave prop simulation to match measured (Nordic tools) - beat that.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for CENOS 3D Antenna Design Simulation software Beta version for free here: https://www.cenos-platform.com/antenna-design

Disclosure: I am Head of Marketing at CENOS.

Answer (score -4):

One approach is to break up the antenna elements into discrete elements that can be modeled with LtSpice that is free.